# How to set wifi ssid specific static ip address in netplan

Tags: networking, server, netplan

I am running ubuntu server in my machine, and using netplan for connecting with wifi.
There are two wifis configured in netplan, one as primary, second as backup

[image]

I have requirement to keep ip address stable for primary wifi, but to keep dynamic for secondary wifi. If I set static IP address, it applies for all wifis.

I already looked at all the example presented at official site : https://netplan.io/examples/
and also gone through their official documentation : https://netplan.io/reference
Checked many stackoverflow answers and askubuntu answers, but still not able to find how to do that.

How to set static IP address for one wifi network but keep other wifi connections default setting?

Comment: There was a bug that was filed for this https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1878168 but whether it was implemented or not in Netplan as a feature I couldn't tell you.  However, someone responded in that bug showing a possible way to assign the static IP when connected to a specific SSID.

Comment: @Visitors Till now I am not able to get solution to that problem. I tried multiple ways, but none worked. I believe it is not possible to have different configurations in above way.